# Как сделать загрузку из json когда элемент в зоне видимости и не сразу все а два объекта.... JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Как сделать загрузку из json когда объект в зоне видимости и не сразу все а два и далее по нажатию кнопки еще два и еще и т.д. в конце когда в json больше ничего нет кнопка удаляется

```
{
"cards": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "image": "example",
        "imageLink": "example",
        "title": "example"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "image": "example",
        "imageLink": "example",
        "title": "example"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "image": "example",
        "imageLink": "example",
        "title": "example"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "image": "example",
        "imageLink": "example",
        "title": "example"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "image": "example",
        "imageLink": "example",
        "title": "example"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "image": "example",
        "imageLink": "example",
        "title": "example"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "image": "example",
        "imageLink": "example",
        "title": "example"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "image": "example",
        "imageLink": "example",
        "title": "example"
    }
]
```

}

```js
const callback = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach(({
    target,
    isIntersecting
  }) => {
    console.log(target);
    if (!isIntersecting) {
      delete getArray();
    }

    getArray()
  })
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  root: document.querySelector("body"),
  threshold: 0
});

document.querySelectorAll(".example__items").forEach(el => observer.observe(el));


async function getArray() {
  const file = "json/data.json";
  let response = await fetch(file, {
    method: "GET"
  });
  if (response.ok) {
    let result = await response.json();
    loadProducts(result);
  } else {
    alert("Ошибка");
  }
}

function loadProducts(data) {
  const productsItems = document.querySelector('.example__items');

  // data.cards.forEach(item => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.cards.length; i++) {
    const productId = data.cards[i].id;
    const productImageLink = data.cards[i].imageLink;
    const productImage = data.cards[i].image;
    const productTitle = data.cards[i].title;

    let productTemplateStart = `<div data-id="${productId}">`;
    let productTemplateEnd = `</div>`;

    let productTemplateBodyStart = `<div">`;
    let productTemplateBodyEnd = `</div>`;

    let productTemplateImage = `
                <a href="${productImageLink}">
                    <img src="${productImage}" alt="">
                </a>
                `;

    let productTemplateContent = `
                <span>${productTitle}</span>
                `;

    let productTemplateBody = '';
    productTemplateBody += productTemplateBodyStart;
    productTemplateBody += productTemplateImage;
    productTemplateBody += productTemplateBodyEnd;

    let productTemplate = '';
    productTemplate += productTemplateStart;
    productTemplate += productTemplateBody;
    productTemplate += productTemplateContent;
    productTemplate += productTemplateEnd;

    productsItems.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', productTemplate);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example__body">
  <div class="example__items">
    <div class="example__item item">
      <div class="item__picture">
        <a class="item__link" href="">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="" type="image/webp">
            <img class="item__img" src="" alt="" loading="lazy">
          </picture>
        </a>
      </div><span class="item__title"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="example__item item">
      <div class="item__picture">
        <a class="item__link" href="">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="" type="image/webp">
            <img class="item__img" src="" alt="" loading="lazy">
          </picture>
        </a>
      </div><span class="item__title"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="example__btn" type="button">ещё</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам нужно хранить значение видимых карточек
2. При нажатии на кнопку добавлять элементы в DOM и увеличивать значение видимых карточек
3. При добавлении проверять видимое кол-во с длиной массива.

```js
const SHOW_CARDS = 2;
let _showedCards = 0;
let _initCards = false;

const data = {
  "cards": [{
      "id": 1,
      "image": "example",
      "imageLink": "example",
      "title": "example"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "image": "example",
      "imageLink": "example",
      "title": "example"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "image": "example",
      "imageLink": "example",
      "title": "example"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "image": "example",
      "imageLink": "example",
      "title": "example"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "image": "example",
      "imageLink": "example",
      "title": "example"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "image": "example",
      "imageLink": "example",
      "title": "example"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "image": "example",
      "imageLink": "example",
      "title": "example"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "image": "example",
      "imageLink": "example",
      "title": "example"
    }
  ]
};

const showMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.example__btn');
const productsItems = document.querySelector('.example__items');

const isScrolledIntoView = (el) => {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemTop = rect.top;
    var elemBottom = rect.bottom;
    return elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;;
}

const createCard = (card) => `
  <div data-id="${card.id}">
      <a href="${card.imageLink}">
          <img src="${card.image}" alt="${card.title}">
      </a>
      <span>${card.id} ${card.title}</span>
  </div>
`;

const renderCards = (cards) => {
  for(const card of cards) {
    productsItems.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    createCard(card),
    );
  }
}

const showCards = (cards) => {
  renderCards([...cards].splice(_showedCards, SHOW_CARDS));
  _showedCards += SHOW_CARDS;
  if (_showedCards >= cards.length) {
    showMoreBtn.style = "display: none;";
  }
}

const showMoreClickHandler = () => {
  showCards(data.cards);
}

const loadProducts = () => {
  // fetch
}

const scrollHandler = () => {
  if (!_initCards && isScrolledIntoView(productsItems)) {
    showCards(data.cards);
    _initCards = true;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', loadProducts);
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
showMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', showMoreClickHandler);
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px"></div>
<div class="example__body">
  <div class="example__items">
    <div class="example__item item">
      <div class="item__picture">
        <a class="item__link" href="">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="" type="image/webp">
            <img class="item__img" src="" alt="" loading="lazy">
          </picture>
        </a>
      </div><span class="item__title"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="example__item item">
      <div class="item__picture">
        <a class="item__link" href="">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="" type="image/webp">
            <img class="item__img" src="" alt="" loading="lazy">
          </picture>
        </a>
      </div><span class="item__title"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="example__btn" type="button">ещё</button>
</div>
```

Исправил код и добавил рендер первых карточек при скроле.
Если вы хотите показывать новые элементы при скроле, то нужно сделать отдельный div для отслеживания внизу и проверять его на видимость.

Функция проверки видимости взята со [scackoverfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: [https://codepen.io/slagrach/pen/xxzZzLy] все хорошо только не пойму почему две карточки пропускает 5-6?  И что нужно добавить чтоб эти две загружались только когда example__body виден? При скролле менять значение SHOW_CARDS?

Comment: Добавил пример в ответ. Константа SHOW_CARDS отвечает только за то, сколко карточек показывать при вызове функции showCards(cards: Card[]): void